# Why is the code after yield return not executed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, async-await

The GameObject in my Unity project should deactivate and then reactivate after a set time. It does deactivate but never reactivates. The object does not deactivate itself so it cant be because of that.

neither

```
public class PickupController : MonoBehaviour
{ 
    public IEnumerator Reactivate(float seconds, GameObject target)
    {
        target.SetActive(false);
        while (!target.gameObject.active)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(seconds);
        }
        target.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

or

```
public class PickupController : MonoBehaviour
{ 
    public IEnumerator Reactivate(float seconds, GameObject target)
    {
        target.SetActive(false);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(seconds);
        target.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

works.

Thanks for the help. :)

Comment: So it sets the target as inactive, and then it waits until it becomes **active**, and then it activates it? That logic doesn't make any sense to me, are you sure it is correct?

Comment: I know, seems weird but it was one of the solutions i found. The second one should work tho.

Comment: Even if i put code directly behind the yield return inside the while loop it dosnt execute though. Meaning that it breaks the loop right away.

Comment: How are you  enumerating over `Reactivate()`?

Comment: Iam calling it using `StartCoroutine();`

Comment: Do you get any errors ?

Answer (score 1):

To add to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74233640/7111561) from how you implemented and describe this to me it seems like you are calling this the following way

```
public class ScriptOnYourTargetObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    
        ...
        StartCoroutine(thePickupController.Reactivate(6, gameObject);
        ...
}
```

=> This would mean the routine still **STOPS** the moment this object is deactivated!

In which script the `IEnumerator` is implemented doesn't mater but on which `MonoBehaviour` instance you are executing `StartCoroutine` since this instance will be running the routine!

If this is the case you could change that and rather go e.g.

```
public class PickupController : MonoBehaviour
{ 
    public void Reactivate(float seconds, GameObject target)
    {
        StartCoroutine(ReactivateRoutine(seconds, target));
    }

    private IEnumerator ReactivateRoutine(float seconds, GameOvbject target)
    {
        target.SetActive(false);
        while (!target.gameObject.active)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(seconds);
        }
        target.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

---

If actually everything is like you say, the object running the routine is not deactivated then I guess the last thing to check would only be:

Do you maybe play around with the `Time.timeScale`?

If this is set to something smaller then `1` then `WaiForSeconds` will take accordingly longer. If it is set to `0` then `WaitForSeconds` will never finish

=> use [`WaitForSecondsRealtime`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSecondsRealtime.html) instead

Comment: Yea, iam basically doing it like you said in the first part of you answer.
`    public void Reactivate(float seconds, GameObject target)
    {
        ...
        StartCoroutine(LoopReactivate());
    }

    public IEnumerator LoopReactivate()
    {
        while (_lastTime + _seconds > Time.time)
        {
            yield return LoopReactivate();
        }

        _target.SetActive(true);
    }`

Ill try it as you described in the second part. Thanks for the lengthy response, always love how incredebly helpful people are on here. :))

Answer (score 0):

Coroutines are stopped when you deactivate the GameObject the coroutine is attached to. Or, I could just quote the Unity docs [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html):

> To stop a coroutine, use StopCoroutine and StopAllCoroutines. **A coroutine also stops if you’ve set SetActive to false to disable the GameObject
> the coroutine is attached to**. Calling Destroy(example) (where example is a MonoBehaviour instance) immediately triggers OnDisable and Unity processes the coroutine, effectively stopping it. Finally, OnDestroy is invoked at the end of the frame.

If this is the functionality you’re looking for, use a coroutine attached to a *different* GameObject. It looks like your code was trying to do just that, with the `target` argument.

Comment: that is exactly what iam already doing :)

Answer (score 0):

Since I can not yet add a comment, I would suggest a possible solution.

You can try and disable your object from a different script that is not attached into the object that you want to disable, by that you will only need a reference to the object.